# discord bot is replying to every message that contains a word from a phrase in a list

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
    return

List = open("D:/code/code/DIscord bot/myFile.txt").readlines()
List = str(List).replace("\\n", " ")
if message.content in List:
    msg = 'REAL!'
    await message.reply(msg)
```

im trying to get the bot to read all the sentences in a .txt file (one sentence per row) and then when that phrase is said in discord, itll respond with "REAL!" this all works but it seems to also respond to every message sent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to follow the rules of this site. Copy the relevant code in your queston

Comment: Which generally means your if statement is always true if it's responding to every message.

Comment: yes thats whats happening, i want it so its only true if a user says a full sentence

Comment: General debugging would be printing out message.content and List to see if you are getting the right values. Also List is orange so try using a different variable name since those are kind of special.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `List` to be a string, not an array. What you likely want is this:

```
List = open("D:/code/code/DIscord bot/myFile.txt").readlines()
List = str(List).split("\\n")
```

This allows your `in` statement to check for entire sentences instead of individual words. Note, you may want to convert all the text to lowercase or do something of that sort.

Comment: when using .split, it comes up with this when i print the list: ["['one\\n', 'two\\n', 'three\\n', 'four\\n', 'five\\n', 'six']"]

Comment: Then use split("\\n") @Isohel

Comment: it then does this ["['one", "', 'two", "', 'three", "', 'four", "', 'five", "', 'six']"]     i tried to do split("'") but didnt work @QWERTYL

Comment: Well you didn't put your data format in the question but obviously You'd have to do `.split("\\n',")`, and then remove the first two and last to characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking this in the context of the discord
API, but it could easily be reduced to a
simple `str` [unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase).

You're checking whether `message.content in List`.
An [equivalent check](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), which would yield
greater diagnostic value, is

```
    if List.find(message.content) > -1:
```

Why? Because upon unwanted match,
you could log the numeric `.find()` result
and examine the portion of List which
matched. This includes examining the
match length -- sometimes we see the
empty string or another very short match
which appears in the larger haystack.

Log both strings, understand where
the match is, and revise your logic.
Do this within a discord handler,
or more conveniently within a TestCase.

---

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) asks that the identifier be spelled `lst`.

---

Using the same identifier to denote
first a vector and then a string
is not improving the readability
of the code.
The Hare and the Hatter ask that
we say what we mean,
and mean what we say.
The name was accurate upon initial
assignment, but less so when
re-assigned.

Comment: it comes up with this:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: doing this makes the bot reply when even 1 letter from the sentences is said in discord

Comment: You must be running code different from OP, which is (1.) `List = str(List).replace("\\n", " ")` , (2.)
`if message.content in List:` . I will assume you've not redefined `str`. Then for any `x = str( ... )`, it's a sure thing that `x.find(y)` will return an integer, rather than a "no attribute" diagnostic. Recycling same identifier to have very different meanings seems to be impacting our ability to clearly communicate algorithmic ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line into

```py
List = str(List).replace("\\n", " ")
```

This

```py
List = list(map(lambda item: item.strip(), List))
```

This will remove `\n` from all the strings in the collection, and maintain the list datatype

Comment: anytime, enjoy the adventure of programming! @Isohel

Comment: oh and another thing, i want the bot to search for those sentences inside other sentences. for example if the bot is searching for “i love coding” it’ll find it in “man i gotta say i love coding” @Skarlett